Column has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index error in Azure Databricks while creating new table in Data warehouse
We are using Azure Databricks notebook where we are connecting Azure Datawarehouse service to get records from a table and copy the data of that table into another table in our Sandbox schema.
Here is the code,
jdbcHostname = "sqldwserver.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = 1433
jdbcDatabase = "sqldwdb"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectProperties = {
"user" : dbutils.secrets.get(scope='DWH_Scope_IT_Data_Users', key='sql_username'),
"password" : dbutils.secrets.get(scope='DWH_Scope_IT_Data_Users', key='sql_password'),
"driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}



Customers_query = "(SELECT TOP 10 * FROM RAW_IT_NO_CLOSED.PT) demoalias"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=Customers_query, properties=connectProperties)

# Define the SCHEMA and target table
target_table = "Sandbox_IT.Analysis1"

# SQL query to create the target table if it does not already exist
create_table_query = """
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Sandbox_IT' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Testing1')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Sandbox_IT.Testing1 (
        PROCEDURE_CD VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        PROCEDURE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(512) NULL,
        PROCESSING_DATE DATE NOT NULL
    )
END
"""

# Function to execute a SQL query using the Spark JDBC connection
def execute_query(query):
    # Establish JDBC connection to execute SQL commands
    conn = None
    stmt = None
    try:
        conn = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
            jdbcUrl,
            connectProperties["user"],
            connectProperties["password"]
        )
        stmt = conn.createStatement()
        stmt.execute(query)
    finally:
        if stmt is not None:
            stmt.close()
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()

# Execute the create table query
execute_query(create_table_query)

# Write the DataFrame to the target table
df.write.jdbc(
    url=jdbcUrl,
    table=target_table,
    mode="append",  # Use "overwrite" if you want to replace the existing data
    properties=connectProperties
)

The above code display the result but fails to create the new table in Sandbox schema and  we are getting Column 'PROCEDURE_CD' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index error for our column.
Full error added at last.
I tried changing the datatype to Char, Nvarchar etc, also increase size of variable and even kept it max but still its not working.
Can anyone please let me know how can we fix this error?
Complete Error --
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement failed. Column 'PROCEDURE_CD' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-1365204618373826>, line 53
     50 execute_query(create_table_query)
     52 # Write the DataFrame to the target table
---> 53 df.write.jdbc(
     54     url=jdbcUrl,
     55     table=target_table,
     56     mode="append",  # Use "overwrite" if you want to replace the existing data
     57     properties=connectProperties
     58 )

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py:48, in _wrap_function.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46 start = time.perf_counter()
     47 try:
---> 48     res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49     logger.log_success(
     50         module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature
     51     )
     52     return res

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:1984, in DataFrameWriter.jdbc(self, url, table, mode, properties)
   1982 for k in properties:
   1983     jprop.setProperty(k, properties[k])
-> 1984 self.mode(mode)._jwrite.jdbc(url, table, jprop)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1355, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1349 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1350     self.command_header +\
   1351     args_command +\
   1352     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1354 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1355 return_value = get_return_value(
   1356     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1358 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1359     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:188, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    186 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    187     try:
--> 188         return f(*a, **kw)
    189     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    190         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o407.jdbc.
: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement failed. Column 'PROCEDURE_CD' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1676)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:907)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:802)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3916)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:268)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:242)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:742)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.createTable(JdbcDialects.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.saveTableToJDBC(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.$anonfun$sideEffectResult$1(commands.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$3(QueryExecution.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(QueryExecution.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$9(SQLExecution.scala:303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:482)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$withMVTagsIfNecessary(QueryExecution.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:465)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:424)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:853)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:199)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)


provide me the sample data you using to write the data to target table.

is below provided solution working for you?

You are not creating your target table Sandbox_IT.Analysis1 in  create_table_query.
You just creating CREATE TABLE Sandbox_IT.Testing1.
Either you give target table as Sandbox_IT.Testing1 in write operation or create table Sandbox_IT.Analysis1 like below.
df.write.jdbc(
    url=jdbcUrl,
    table="Sandbox_IT.Testing1",
    mode="append",
    properties=connectProperties
)

or create below table
create_table_query = """
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Sandbox_IT' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Analysis1')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE Sandbox_IT.Analysis1 (
        PROCEDURE_CD VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        PROCEDURE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(512) NULL,
        PROCESSING_DATE DATE NOT NULL
    )
END
"""

